# Имитация погрузки товаров через js или ajax как сделать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как вот такую вещь можно реализовать?
Должна быть реализована подгрузка товаров на условном ajax (можно имитировать любым образом так как бэкенда нет)
Как я понимаю сверстать блоки в которых будет выводиться инфа а далее выводить инфу о к примеру 6 товарах в эти блоки. И судя по всему это вся каша идет в массив который нужно будет разделить и вывести в каждый блок. Поправьте если ошибаюсь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сверстать готовый для вставки кусок html, затем подгрузить его аяксом и встаить в страницу. Т.к. вы уже используете jquery, проще всегь будет воспользоваться функцией [jQuery.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/).

Както так:

```
$('#place_to_insert').load('path_to.html');
```

Код загрузит с сервера фаил `path_to.htlm` и вставит его содержимое в узел с `id=palce_to_insert`.

Если хотите передавать с сервера не html, а json/xml с даннымиб то рекомендую взглянуть на готовые шаблонизаторы.

Статьи на хабре:

https://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/151700/

https://habrahabr.ru/post/219873/

загружать данные (без автоматической вставки в узел) можно методами [`jQuery.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [`jQuery.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) или [`jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).